# vis.js network fit function

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am using vis.js 4.16.1 to draw the network graphs. Currently I have two network graphs. One network graph for the user drawing. After the user has done, I want to copy exactly whatever the network graph is to the second network graph. However, I can't set the same viewpoint as the first one. This is the options for the first network:

```
options = {
    locale: 'en',
    physics: {
        "enabled": false,
    },
    edges: {
        smooth: {
            type: 'continuous'
        }
    },
    interaction: {
        navigationButtons: true,
        selectConnectedEdges: false
    }
};
```

I have disabled the physics to allow the user organize the node themselves.
This is the options for the second network:

```
var options = {
    locale: 'en',
    physics: {
        "enabled": false
    },
    edges: {
        smooth: {
            type: 'continuous'
        }
    },
    interaction: {
        dragNodes: false,
        dragView:true
    }
};
```

When I use the fit function (http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~mike/myrlibrary/visNetwork/doc/network/)

```
var fitOption = {
    nodes: nodes.getIds() //nodes is type of vis.DataSet contains all the nodes
}
secondNetwork.fit(fitOption);
```

There is nothing changed.
When I use the `moveTo` function:

```
var centerOptions = {
    position: {
        x: firstNetwork.getViewPosition().x, 
        y: firstNetwork.getViewPosition().y},
    }
}
secondNetwork.moveTo(centerOptions);
```

Still, I can't move my canvas to the point where the first network focused on. The canvas is not moving at all. 
Could someone give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Reiner, I have figure out the reason why fit() and moveTo() function are not working in my context, I need set the option:

```
 physics: {
     "enabled": true
 }
```

otherwise it's not working. What did is before I call my fit() function, change enabled to true, call fit() function, then set enabled to false.

Comment: if you have found a solution, please accept your own answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `network.fit()`, this will do the same as the upper button in the right-bottom corner. So all nodes will be focused.

You can use the Dataset-object for nodes and edges, than it its rather easy to copy all the nodes and edges to the same xy-coordinates with

```
var xy = network1.edges.get(); 
network2.edges.add(xy);
```